# How should I connect my compressor effect to my amplifier?

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers, guitar-effects, compression

Just bought an ENGL screamer 50W amplifier and the only thing I miss right now is a decent compressor for the clean channel.

I also have a Zoom g9.2tt effects device and I was thinking of connecting it using a patch with a compressor effect only.

My question is how do I connect the zoom with the amplifier ? (I used to connect it via the input socket of my old 15W amplifier and never thought to much on the impact of the sound).

Bare in mind that the zoom contains tubes as well so I do not want the sound to be muffled or something like that.

What is the best way to do this without loosing the quality of the signal ?

Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very localised, specific question so out may be closed, however a general answer is that you would just use the compressor in the  normal signal chain:

```
--------   ------------   -----   ----------
|guitar|---|compressor|---|amp|---|speakers|
--------   ------------   -----   ----------
```

Your other option is to put it in the effects loop but generally you want the compressor first.

Your comment about the tubes is a little irrelevant, as you are only using the compression anyway.

Comment: doesn't the signal pass through the tubes anyway ? As I change the tubes solid state and gain I do feel the change even with a compressor only